# Rearrange items in order reduce fragmentation and reduce wasted space

Tags: algorithms, optimization, approximation, heuristics, memory-allocation

I have a segment with some offsets at irregular intervals

[image]

There are items of various length inside. Items cannot be placed randomly. Instead, their left side must match some offset.

Items are free to go past offests.

As you can see in this image, item number 3 is long enough that it goes through an offset, shown with a dotted line.

[image]

I also have some special type of offset that I'll call "barrier" that items cannot go past and cannot be placed on:

[image]

One last constraint is that items cannot overlap each other:

[image]

Items can be moved one at a time. So I can pick up an item and place it somewhere else as long as no constraint is violated.

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm/solver/optimizer which would find some good enough sequence of steps to reduce fragmentation and compact up these items. It follows that this procedure will reduce empty space between items and offsets:

[image]

Can you give some suggstion on how you would tackle a problem like this or point me in the right direction, give some ideas, name algorithms to take inspiration from, etc..?

Comment: May be It is a special type of bin packing problem. i.e. Let k be the number of barriers, then (k+1) is the number of bins where each bin has a size [i, i+1] where i and i+1 are the barriers in the segment or the starting/ending point of the segment. Items $a_1, ..., a_n$ can be placed in these bins so that we maximize the space in each bin.

Comment: @YOUSEFY would that take offsets into account and minimize movements though?

Comment: If offsets plays as barriers, then add all of them to k.